# Plot a system of equations in R

Tags: r, plot, linear-regression

Suppose you have a system of equations (5 equations and 2 variables) that look like this:

```
Ax + By = C

AB <- matrix(runif(10), 5)
C <- c(5, 10, 15, 20, 25)
```

How do you plot this system of equations in R, without first manually converting into

```
y = (C - Ax) / B
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
set.seed(101)
AB <- matrix(runif(10), 5)
C <- c(5, 10, 15, 20, 25)

x = seq(-70,70,1)

plot(x, (C[1] - AB[1,1]*x)/AB[1,2], col=1, type="l", ylim=c(-100,200))

for (i in 2:nrow(AB)) {
    lines(x, (C[i] - AB[i,1]*x)/AB[i,2], col=i, type="l")
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! Thank you! That's very helpful!